# Camera2 API .close() causes major frame drop

Tags: java, android, optimization, android-camera, android-camera2

I've got an app in which I have camera1 api for the front camera and camera2 api for the back camera (don't worry, I've got a camera1 back activity as well).

When I go from back camera to front camera, I get a msg in LogCat telling me I skipped 50+ frames, which is enough to cause a serious looking lag in the UI/UX.

Any ideas on how to avoid this lag ? seems like mCameraDevice.close() is a real killer !

Comment: You probably open the camera on UI thread. Try to use a separate Handler thread for this, and all camera callbacks will also run on that secondary thread.

Comment: I open the camera via mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraID, mCamera2StateCallBack, mCameraHandler);

Comment: if `mCameraHandler` uses the main Looper, you gain nothing. And then you have the front camera to open correctly.

Comment: Nope my Handler gets a HandlerThread looper

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51973715/close-cameradevice-in-a-seperate-thread